# How to select first row from a join that returns multple rows on the primary key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, greatest-n-per-group

This is related to this question:  [Joining multiple tables results in duplicate rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103262/joining-multiple-tables-results-in-duplicate-rows/103264)

I have two tables that I am joining.  They share a key. The person table has one name per primary key but the email table has multiple emails per personId.  I want to only show the first email per person.  Presently I get multiple rows per person because they have multiple emails. I am running SQL-Server 2005.

EDIT: This is T-SQL. 
First email is literally the first email row per person.

Edit 2:
First email as I see it would be the first email row that shows up in the join as SQL works through the query.  I does not matter which email shows up.  Only that no more than one email shows up.  I hope that makes it clearer.

```
Table1: Person
Table2: Email

Select Person.PersonName, Email.Email
From person 
left join on Person.ID=Email.PersonId;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "first" email?  What sort criteria determines "first"?

Comment: did you try top 1?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: The **"the first email row per person"** does not really tell us anything. "First" by what criteria? SQL tables have no inherent order.

Comment: @ypercube Could you suggest possible criteria because I do not have any at present other than I only want one row per user ID/ Person.  It does not matter which email appears, just that only one appears.

Comment: Well, that's one valid criterion: "I don't care which row, just one".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
SELECT
    A.PersonName, A.Email
FROM
        (
        Select Person.PersonName, Email.Email
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Person.ID ORDER BY Email.Email) AS RN
        From person 
        left join Email on Person.ID=Email.PersonId
        ) A
WHERE A.RN = 1
```

Comment: What is the 'A'?  Is it an abbreviation of the table name?

Comment: @normandantzig That's an [alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: 1. ) Did you alias both of my tables using the From (Select Person.PersonName, Email.Email
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Person.ID ORDER BY Email.Email) AS RN
From person 
left join on Person.ID=Email.PersonId) A   And 2. ) so that you could refer to both columns using A as the table?

Comment: What is inside the parenthesis is called a **derived table**. It's a valid table, just as base tables but it's lifetime is only for the duration of the query execution. It must have a name (or alias) and @sabin chose to name it `A`. This table has 3 columns (PersonName, Email, RN) and outside of the parentheses, you can use `A.Email` just as you can use `tablename.columnname` for every other table in your code.

Comment: Care to explain your answer?

Comment: @CardinalSystem, on the record set (Person left join email) , we are adding a new a new column, RN  . The values are 1,2,... for the same  value on person.ID  (PARTITION BY Person.ID given the ORDER BY) . When we have a new value on person.ID, the value is reset  to 1 and so on ... here is a small sample https://dbfiddle.uk/8m2xs_VU

Answer (score 15):

I would use an outer apply for this, I find it more readable.

```
Select Person.PersonName, coalesce(Email.Email,'No email found.') as Email
From person 
outer apply (
  select top(1) Email.Email 
  from Email 
  where Person.ID=Email.PersonId
  order by <whatever suits you>
) as Email;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select
  P.PersonID,
  (SELECT TOP 1 E.Email FROM Email E WHERE E.PersonID = P.PersonID ORDER BY <pick your column here>)
from
  Person P
```

Comment: What is the 'P'.  Is it an abbreviation of the table name?

Comment: 'P' is an alias for Person.  It follows the table declaration in the FROM clause.

Comment: @normandantzig Both are valid in SQL Server in most situations.

Answer (score 5):

As it does not matter which email shows up. I think that the following one is very direct.

```
Select Person.PersonName,  MIN(Email.Email)
From person 
left join email 
on Person.ID=Email.PersonId
group by Person.Id, Person.PersonName
```